# MSBuild Access Property Group declared in a Target outside

Tags: msbuild, msbuild-target

I'm having problem in accessing a PropertyGroup which is declared inside a target.

Message inside Target is publishing the version number correctly. When i try to publish the VersionNumber and VersionInfo ,I’m able to see only correct value for VersionInfo as true but VersionNumber is displayed as empty string.I want the VersionNumber value also published here

Please help !

Below is my code file :

```
<PropertyGroup >
  <FileLocation>C:\Dev\version.txt</FileLocation>
    <VersionInfo>false</VersionInfo>
    <VersionInfo Condition="Exists('C:\Dev\version.txt')">true</VersionInfo>
  </PropertyGroup>

<Target Name="ReadFromFile">
  <ReadLinesFromFile File="$(FileLocation)" >
    <Output PropertyName="VersionNumber"
        TaskParameter="Lines"/>
  </ReadLinesFromFile>
  <Message Text="Inside Target (Version Number) : $(VersionNumber)"/>
</Target>

<ItemDefinitionGroup>
  <PreBuildEvent>
    <Command>
      echo VersionNumber: $(VersionNumber)
      echo VersionInfo: $(VersionInfo)
    </Command>
  </PreBuildEvent>
</ItemDefinitionGroup>
```

Comment: Does your Target run before the PreBuildEvent?

Comment: Yes . It will be called before PreBuildEvent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution for my problem.Even i could remove the entire Target-ReadfromFile and could read the text file content in property group itself.I used property function - System.IO.File::ReadAllText to achieve my functionality.
It turned out to be a simple solution

More details about property functions can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/property-functions)

My code looks like below now :

```
<PropertyGroup >
  <FileLocation>C:\Dev\version.txt</FileLocation>
    <VersionInfo>false</VersionInfo>
    <VersionInfo Condition="Exists('C:\Dev\version.txt')">true</VersionInfo>
  <VersionDetails>$([System.IO.File]::ReadAllText($(FileLocation)))</VersionDetails>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Now i can access VersionDetails property anywhere in the project

Comment: Yes. They are. Even validation using Regex was very simple in one line avoiding multiple lines of code in batch / Target groups